# Can I use SVG in IMG tags in browsers yet?

Tags: svg

This question may be better rephrased how do I know when I can use this feature listed on "can i use.com" but my question is can I use SVG in the IMG tag yet? http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It works in all browsers that people actually use today. Don't forget to set the width and height of your image.

Answer (score 2):

This will mostly be an opinionated answer. Since iOS is a very big deal for websites and [iOS 9 adoption is steady](http://www.theverge.com/2015/9/21/9364169/ios-9-adoption-fastest-ever) I suggest to use `svg` in `img` tag depending on what your analytics say regarding users using iOS 8.4 or below, note this is for inlining the svg data.

Otherwise is a resounding yes.

Comment: So it is supported on iOS 9 but not before that? Ergg just read it's partially supported before that. Just data uri does not work. Which is a big deal or no?

Comment: I don't ready the question as a question of inlining SVG with a src="data:...". If you're correct then I agree with your answer, but for a regular .svg file it works just fine in iOS 8.x.

Comment: <img src="somefile.svg"> works fine in most versions of iOS.

Comment: @JohanNordberg, yes, I was referring to inlining the src on the svg specifically, which is also another issue with IE < 11 not mentioned in caniuse